# How to detect my device left/right audio balance?

Tags: android, audio, audio-player

Is there a way to programmatically detect the current device's audio balance?
On Android 10 - the setting that I'm willing to detect is under:

*Settings -> Accessibility -> Audio & On-Screen Text -> Audio balance*
Also shown [here](https://mcmw.abilitynet.org.uk/adjust-leftright-volume-balance-android-10)

By changing this balance we as users can set either the left side or the right side of the stereo volume louder.
Can I somehow retrieve this value in my app?

Answer (score 1):

This only works system-wide since Android Q and this would be the [Settings.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/provider/Settings.java):

```
/**
 * Master balance (float -1.f = 100% left, 0.f = dead center, 1.f = 100% right).
 *
 * @hide
 */
public static final String MASTER_BALANCE = "master_balance";
```

These global settings can only be read (not tested, but something alike this):

```
Settings.Global.getFloat(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.MASTER_BALANCE, 0f)
```

I could not find any public API for the system-wide setting (which means, that only the `DevicePolicyManager` could change it), but one can use [`MediaPlayer.setVolume (float leftVolume, float rightVolume)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer#setVolume(float,%20float)) to control this for the playback of the own application.

Comment: Thanks. I have tried to read this setting on my minSdk Android Q project, but it seems like there is no MASTER_BALANCE constant inside my Settings.Global class, do I need to import/change anything in order to get this value?

Comment: Moreover, when I try to read the value "master_balance" that I declare by myself, unfortunately, it doesn't return anything.